# Basic Sprite not loading - AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

Hello I have just started with AndEngine. I have been working with a tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GanqzGOWRBE). I thought it was pretty straightforward but I can't seem to get it to work properly. The purpose is simply to display a simple Sprite. I did the code precisely how the tutorial instructed but when I run the game, nothing loads at all. I threw in some Log.i statements and it doesn't appear that any of the basic methods (OnCreateResources etc...) run at all. I'm not getting any errors but the nothing is running either. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

(I hope this isn't a stupid question) Code is below:

```
public class GameMain extends BaseGameActivity {

Scene scene;
protected static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
protected static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
BitmapTextureAtlas playerTexture;
ITextureRegion playerTextureRegion;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_main);
    Log.i("TEST", "CREATE GAME");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Camera mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    EngineOptions options = new EngineOptions(true,
            ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(
                    CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
    return options;
}

@Override
public void onCreateResources(
        OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("TEST", "LOADING GFX");
    loadGFX();
    pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();

}

private void loadGFX() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("TEST", "LOAD GFX");
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    playerTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 64, 64);
    playerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(playerTexture, this, "star.png", 0, 0);
    playerTexture.load();
}

@Override
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("TEST", "Scene Background");
    this.scene = new Scene();
    this.scene.setBackground(new Background(0, 125, 58));

    pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(this.scene);

}

@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
        OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Sprite sPlayer = new Sprite(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2,
            playerTextureRegion,
            this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    sPlayer.setRotation(45.0f);
    this.scene.attachChild(sPlayer);
    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a short look at the tutorial, i didn't see anything about overwriting the `onCreate` method, esp. the `setContentView` part could be wrong.

makes me wonder, that none of the `Log.i` calls appear in your log, did you set your log to a higher level than info?

let me take a deeper look, if these two hints where not right ;-)

Comment: Thanks for response. I commented out onCreate but then the whole screen goes dark. But you seem right the onCreate etc. don't appear to be in the tutorial.

Comment: that's nothing bad in this case - did you check your log level and still don't get any logcat entries?

Comment: Correct. I placed Log statements around all the methods, and no logcat entries.

Comment: tested the code and it seems to work the way it should - do you have any other activity except the `GameMain` in your project and does your manifest.xml use `GameMain` inside the activity tag?

Comment: No I don't. In fact I actually copy pasted the tutorial source code into my project and the screen just goes dark. I have no idea what's happening.

Comment: Wait! Got it to work, problem was the the line  playerTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 64, 64); - I changed it to 1024 (from a different post) and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: :-O fine to see it working, but what andEngine version are you on? GLES2 warns me about my atlas beeing to small (and in this case, the atlas was large enough for the image from the website)

Comment: It's GLES2. I think the difference is the type of device I'm using. I using an actual tablet and not the emulator.